# How to transform correctly an array to json_encode

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I found this and its very helpful...

[Demo: jQuery Ajax Call to PHP Script with JSON Return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30037626/demo-jquery-ajax-call-to-php-script-with-json-return/51809496#51809496)

But i have some problem with to use it....

I need to understand how to use it correctly...

I dont understand why my array cannot be transform in a json....

These code are in response.php :

```
$champs = ["user" => "", "combinaison" => 0, "valeurSmall" => "", "valeurBig" => "", "aucune_valeur" => false, "trop_valeur" => false, "color_red" => 0, "color_green" => 0, "color_blue" => 0];

$return["json"] = json_encode($champs, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT); 
echo json_encode($return);
```

And in my index.html the part javascript :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "changerMise/changer.php", 
    data: data,
    success: function(dataReturn) {                    
    alert("Form submitted successfully.\nReturned json: " + dataReturn["json"] );
       }
   });
```

The alert dont come back with the thing i need to use after....

The result gave :

```
Form submitted successfully.
Returned json: {"aucune_valeur": true}
```

any ideas ?!??!

Thx guys

Comment: `echo json_encode($champs,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);` ...

Answer (score 0):

Are you has give header json for response output on top of your php file, like below ?

```
<?php header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8"); ?>
```

Comment: If you using POST method you must know where data name/value will be executed/inspected. $_POST["json"] example, there data from inputed form will be executed/testing.

Comment: You must add header json, and add allow cors origins

Comment: Yes. Ajax json must be reading json object (not html). I think your PHP returned html header, not json.

Comment: I know why i didnt receive any information at my output responce...At the end of one of my function, i forgot this ««««return $champs;»»»

Please don't throw any rotten tomatoes lol